# Emitting events to self on the client for socket.io-client

Tags: javascript, node.js, socket.io

In the old versions of Socket.IO (version <1.0), the [namespace](https://github.com/socketio/socket.io-client/blob/0.9.10/lib/namespace.js#L43) of the socket.io-client includes the $emit function to its prototype. I am yet to understand this properly but with this, events from the client can be emitted to the same client locally.

However, in the latest version of Socket.IO, an emit function is not accessible outside of the [Socket](https://github.com/socketio/socket.io-client/blob/master/lib/socket.js#L47) module.

The question is: is there still a way to emit an event from the client to itself?

Comment: What problem are you really trying to solve?  You can always get access to the original eventEmitter `.emit()` via `EventEmitter.prototype.emit()` and can use `.call()` with it to apply it to any EventEmitter object.

Comment: I am trying to update codes that have been using an old version of socket.io (0.9.x) to socket.io (1.4.x). However, they had a code where they emit events from the client that are listened to by itself.

And so, since with the old version of socket.io, the emitter is accessible outside of the Namespace module, this was done simply by calling the $emit function. But with the newer versions, the same emitter is not accessible anymore. Hence, the question.

Also, the answer you provided did solve the question. Thank you very much.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I will make my comment into an answer since it appears to have helped you solve the issue.

If you want access to the original `.emit()` method, you can get it from `EventEmitter.prototype.emit()` and use `.call()` to call it on the appropriate object that has appropriate event handlers on it.

```
EventEmitter.prototype.emit.call(someObj, "myMsg", mydata);
```

Comment: Thank you for the answer, but I have to confirm. Calling the EventEmitter on the browser side is not possible, right?